# Memory growing unexpectedly while using entity framework to bulk insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have to process like 1M entities to build facts. There should be about the same amount of resulting facts (1 million).

The first issue that I had was the bulk insert it was slow with entity framework. So I used this pattern [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework) (answer from SLauma). And I can insert entities real fast now about 100K in one minute.

Another issue I ran into is the lack of memory to process everything. So I've "paged" the processing. To avoid out of memory exception I would get if I make a list out of my 1 million resulting facts.

The issue I have is that the memory is always growing even with the paging and I don't understand why. After each batch no memory is released. I think this is weird because i fetch recons build facts and store them into the DB at each iteration of the loop. As soon as the loop is completed those should be released from memory. But it look like not because no memory is released after each iteration.

Can you please tell me if you see something wrong before I dig more ? More specifically why no memory is released after an iteration of the while loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext db = new ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext();

  var recon = db.Recons
    .Where(r => r.Transacs.Where(t => t.ItemCodeDetails.Count > 0).Count() > 0)
    .OrderBy( r => r.ReconNum);

  // used for "paging" the processing
  var processed = 0;
  var total = recon.Count();
  var batchSize = 1000; //100000;
  var batch = 1;
  var skip = 0;
  var doBatch = true;

  while (doBatch)
  { // list to store facts processed during the batch
    List<ReconFact> facts = new List<ReconFact>();
    // get the Recon items to process in this batch put them in a list
    List<Recon> toProcess = recon.Skip(skip).Take(batchSize)
      .Include(r => r.Transacs.Select(t => t.ItemCodeDetails))
      .ToList();
    // to process real fast 
    Parallel.ForEach(toProcess, r =>
    { // processing a recon and adding the facts to the list
      var thisReconFacts = ReconFactGenerator.Generate(r);
      thisReconFacts.ForEach(f => facts.Add(f));
      Console.WriteLine(processed += 1);
    });
    // saving the facts using pattern provided by Slauma
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)))
    {
      ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext context = null;
      try
      {
        context = new ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext();
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var fact in facts.Where(f => f != null))
        {
          count++;
          Console.WriteLine(count);
          context = ContextHelper.AddToContext(context, fact, count, 250, true); //context.AddToContext(context, fact, count, 250, true);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
      }
      finally
      {
        if (context != null)
          context.Dispose();
      }
      scope.Complete();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("batch {0} finished continuing", batch);
    // continuing the batch
    batch++;
    skip = batchSize * (batch - 1);
    doBatch = skip < total;
    // AFTER THIS facts AND toProcess SHOULD BE RESET 
    // BUT IT LOOKS LIKE THEY ARE NOT OR AT LEAST SOMETHING
    // IS GROWING IN MEMORY 
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Processing is done {} recons processed", processed);
}
```

The method provided by Slauma to optimize bulk insert with entity framework.

```
class ContextHelper
{
  public static ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext AddToContext(ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext context,
  ReconFact entity, int count, int commitCount, bool recreateContext)
  {
    context.Set<ReconFact>().Add(entity);

    if (count % commitCount == 0)
    {
      context.SaveChanges();
      if (recreateContext)
      {
        context.Dispose();
        context = new ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext();
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
      }
    }
    return context;
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, be very careful with statements such as `thisReconFacts.ForEach(f => facts.Add(f));` in a `Parallel.ForEach` contexts. `List<T>.Add(T)` is not thread safe.

Comment: Yes I know I should use thread safe collections. I will do that as further improvements. First I had to figure out a fast way of inserting tons of data with EF.

Comment: Who said you should use thread safe collections? What about `List<ReconFact> facts = (from recon in toProcess.AsParallel() from fact in ReconFactGenerator.Generate(recon) select fact).ToList();`?

Comment: Very nice I wasn't aware of this linq method thank you

Comment: even faster way would be using https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to tell the object context not to track the objects, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext db = new ReceiptsItemCodeAnalysisContext();

    var recon = db.Recons
        .AsNoTracking() // <---- add this
        .Where(r => r.Transacs.Where(t => t.ItemCodeDetails.Count > 0).Count() > 0)
        .OrderBy( r => r.ReconNum);

//...
```

In the code you have, all one million Recon objects will accumulate in memory until the object context is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the same data context throughout your run, it's presumably caching.  Generally speaking, when I've faced this issue I've found it simplest to ensure that each "batch" has its own datacontext that goes out of scope per iteration.

Comment: I've tried to create a data context at each iteration but it doesn't change a thing ...

Comment: Even the `recon` db at the top of your method?

Comment: Yes I've tried to put every context instance in a using {} statement but no change unfortunately.